# RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice. out=out, **kwargs)

Tags: python, numpy, math

I've been trying to do some math using numpy but for some reason I'm getting this error

```
/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3420: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  out=out, **kwargs)
/Users/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:188: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

There are only few lines of codes that actually does some math;some subtraction mainly. This is the first time I've encountered this problem. If anyone can help that would be appreciative
Below are my codes.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
from numpy.linalg import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def readfile(file_name):
    file = open(file_name,'r')
    lines = [list(map(int, line.strip("\n").split(","))) for line in file]
    x= np.array(lines)
    file.close()
    return x
X= readfile("LocationB.txt")
def dist(a, b, ax=1):
    return np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=ax)
k = 3
# X coordinates of random centroids
C_x = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-2, size=k)
# Y coordinates of random centroids
C_y = np.random.randint(0, np.max(X)-2, size=k)
C = np.array(list(zip(C_x, C_y)), dtype=np.float32)
# To store the value of centroids when it updates
C_old = np.zeros(C.shape)
# Cluster Lables(0, 1)
clusters = np.zeros(len(X))
# Error func. - Distance between new centroids and old centroids
error = dist(C, C_old, None)
# Loop will run till the error becomes zero
while error != 0:
    # Assigning each value to its closest cluster
    for i in range(len(X)):
        distances = dist(X[i], C)
        cluster = np.argmin(distances)
        clusters[i] = cluster
    # Storing the old centroid values
    C_old = deepcopy(C)
    # Finding the new centroids by taking the average value
    for i in range(k):
        points = [X[j] for j in range(len(X)) if clusters[j] == i]
        C[i] = np.mean(points, axis=0)
    error = dist(C, C_old, None)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y', 'c', 'm']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(k):
        points = np.array([X[j] for j in range(len(X)) if clusters[j] == i])
        ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s=5, c=colors[i])
ax.scatter(C[:, 0], C[:, 1], marker='*', s=200, c='#050505')
plt.show()
```

Comment: make sure that ```X``` array length is more than 0

Comment: yes, the length is longer than zero

Comment: then make sure of two things: 1. ```a``` and ```b``` arguments that passed into ```dist``` function have length more than 0. 2. ```np.max(X)-2``` more than 0

Comment: It will be hard to understand the error without seeing your full code. As @crackanddie mentioned, it is likely due to `np.max(X)-2` not being greater than 0.

Comment: @gofvonx I've updated the codes, if you can please have a look

Comment: @crackanddie     The np.max(X) is 512 which is greater than 0